# How can I find the R values

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I have the following equations :

$$\begin{cases}K = \frac{B – 3}{20}\\
 K = (20S+3)R+S\\
 K = 20S^2 + (20N+7)S + N\\
 N= R - S
\end{cases}$$
 - And I have the $B$ values, e.g : 834343, 3253538, 10^87653

**How can I find the $R$ values?**

or maybe there is no solution for these equations?

Comment: It seems to be the same question as yesterday. Any problem with the answers you received ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: I had mistake yesterday with N = S - R and it should be N = R - S

Comment: Why don't you repeat what Mathlove made ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici : I did it, but I think I did some mistakes and I'm not sure if I solve it right.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Hoping that I did not make mistakes, you can immediately eliminate $K$ from the first equation, $N$ from the fourth equation. Replace in the second and third equations; substract one from the other. You will end with a quadratic equation in $R$.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: I tried, but when I marge forth equation with thread one, the come result is second equation. is this mean there is wrong with my equations and I can't find the values?

Answer (score 0):

$$K = \frac{B – 3}{20}\tag{1}$$
$$ K = (20S+3)R+S\tag{2}$$
$$ K = 20S^2 + (20N+7)S + N\tag{3}$$
$$ N= R - S \tag{4}$$
From (4), $R=S+N$.

Put in (2):
$$K=(20S+3)(N+S)+S=20NS+20S^2+3N+4S\tag{5}$$
Also from (3):
$$K=20S^2+20NS+7S+N\tag{6}$$
Subtract (5) from (6):
$$K-K=(20S^2+20NS+7S+N)-(20NS+20S^2+3N+4S)\\
2N=3S$$
Put $N=\frac32S$ in (6) and use (1):
$$\frac{B-3}{20}=20S^2+20\left(\frac32S\right)S+7S+\frac32S$$
$$50S^2+\frac{17}2S-\frac{B-3}{20}=0$$
Solve it to get $$S:=f(B)$$
Then $$R=\frac52f(B)$$
Spoiler:Form Answer

> $$R = \frac1{80} (\pm\sqrt{40 B+169}-17)$$